# how to write a batch file for opening only one tab in a browser?

Tags: batch-file, window, webbrowser-control

I know how to open a tabs in the browser using batch file, but i want to open a browser which will open only one tab, and prevent the users opening any other tabs in that browser.

Comment: I think this more a browser specific question. For Firefox for example there is browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction (http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.link.open_newwindow.restriction), which might help you. Further googling together with browser names might help.

Comment: Another approach would be to disable tabs (http://askubuntu.com/questions/424396/disable-tabs-in-firefox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution. By creating a shortcut of the opend webpage, one can make a Web App, which can be use as windows app.
And windows apps dose not open the tabs in the browser.

[Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528224/how-to-create-a-batch-file-to-create-a-shortcut-to-a-webpage)