# Create shortcut to website in chrome on desktop automatically

Tags: windows, google-chrome, batch-file, vbscript

I am trying to write a script to automatically save a shortcut to a user's desktop which opens in full screen like an app.

To do this manually you click chrome options -> More Tools -> Add to Desktop
You then need to click open as window and Add, and chrome will save the app to the desktop, and it will open in fullscreen.

[image: Add Shortcut]

I want to be able to automate this so that it can be setup on everyone's computer through group policy, or by the user just running a script.

The shortcut chrome creates is something like `...chrome.exe -app-id=hjnwjndjsn...` So it looks like chrome needs to know about it so it can link it can create the app. i.e. its not just a simple link to chrome with the website url.

I am happy for this be done in any language ... I have put vbscript and batch in the tags just as a suggestion.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528224/how-to-create-a-batch-file-to-create-a-shortcut-to-a-webpage

Comment: You have to type in the address and give the path of the icon file though. I'm sure that you can use it how you want if you modify it a bit. I would but I'm at work at the moment perhaps tonight I'll post an answer in batch.

Comment: Thanks! I've just seen that chrome lets you pass in `--app=http://example.com` and this will open the website in "app mode" i.e. no nav bar etc.
So just need the icon for the shortcut

Comment: No problem :) been quite busy lately however I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Still not full solution of what you intent to. Did you solved it? I was thinking about a button on my app that does exactly what you showed. Eg: Install on desktop and done

Comment: you can just make a chrome shortcut also a simple `start command` could help ad it to a batch file and all done.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about to the desktop but you can echo it

```
echo. 
echo. Website:
echo [InternetShortcut] > "%Path%"
echo URL=%URL_PATH% >> "Path%"
echo idlist= >> "%Path%"
echo.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not that easy, if at all to do, without linking to a batch file in the server.

Hyperlink it to a .bat file which will be like this:

copy \SERVER\FOLDER\FOLDER\SHORTCUT.lnk c:\users\USER\desktop

Easy as can be!

Answer (score 0):

You should see [this link](https://support.microsoft.com/fil-ph/help/244677/how-to-create-a-desktop-shortcut-with-the-windows-script-host),

but here is the code what you need (in VBScript):

To web page:

```
WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
oUrlLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop+"\Microsoft Web Site.URL")
oUrlLink.TargetPath = "http://www.microsoft.com"
oUrlLink.Save
```

To aplication (like "`...chrome.exe -app-id=hjnwjndjsn...`"):

```
oMyShortcut = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop + "\Sample.lnk")
OMyShortcut.TargetPath = "%windir%\notepad.exe"
oMyShortCut.Save
```